# Use Arrays in Twig Template from Custom Block

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I'm attempting to use arrays in a twig template from variables in a custom block.

In my custom block I have

```
public function build() {
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('type','product')
        ->sort('created', 'DESC');

    $nids = $query->execute();
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($nids as $nid) {
        $node = NODE::load($nid);
            $imageurl[$i] = $node->get('field_product_page_display')->entity->getFileuri();
            $title[$i] = $node->get('field_title')->value;
            $imageurl[$i] = str_replace("public://", "", $imageurl[$i]);
            $i += 1;

        }
    return array(
        '#theme' => 'product_display',
        '#imageurl' => $imageurl,
        '#product_title' => $title,
        );
}
```

In my mymodule.module file I have

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array('header' =>
        array(
            'variables' => array(
                'header_title' => 'Default Title',
                'header_size' => 'h1',
                'text_align' => 'center',
                'uppercase' => FALSE,
                'grid_size' => 12,
                ), 
            ),
        'product_display' => 
            array(
                'variables' => array(
                    '#imageurl' => [],
                    '#product_title' => [],
                    ),
                ),
        );
}
```

in my product_display.html.twig file I have

```
{% for product in product_title %}
    {% for image in imageurl %}
         <div class="large-4 medium-3 column">
            <img src="./sites/default/files/{{ image }}">
                        <div class="product-title">
                            {{ product }}
                        </div>
                    </div> 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know for sure that my custom block.php file is able to retrieve the data properly because using Debug() on $imageurl or $title displays all the information. However using Dump() in product-display.html.twig shows the #imageurl and #product_title arrays as empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your hook_theme. Use this instead:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
return array('header' =>
    array(
        'variables' => array(
            'header_title' => 'Default Title',
            'header_size' => 'h1',
            'text_align' => 'center',
            'uppercase' => FALSE,
            'grid_size' => 12,
            ), 
        ),
    'product_display' => 
        array(
            'variables' => array(
                'imageurl' => [],
                'product_title' => [],
                ),
            ),
    );
```

}

The # sign in a render array is used to differenciate a key that has a meaning in the rendering versus an element. It shouldn't be included in the theme definition.

Comment: That is not a syntax error.

Comment: Well, in terms of php it is not. In terms of drupal, I think it is though because the number sign has a special meaning in the render arrays. It might work (not tested it) if the render array has a double number sign like '##imageurl' for variables since it has a number sign in the theme declaration, but I sure wouldn't recommend it as it might have an unexpected behavior.